# Multiple column alphabetical and numerical sort

Tags: filenames, sort

I want to sort

1. based on the file name.
2. For the case where the file name prefix matches and the file ends in a number, I would like to have those numerically sorted based on the number at the end of the file name.

The following

```
cat /tmp/foo.txt | sort -t/ -k3,3 -k3,3n
```

accomplishes 1, but not 2.

#### Input `/tmp/foo.txt`

```
dirA/catA/apple.txt
dirA/catA/addition.txt
dirA/catA/difference
dirA/catB/binary.txt
dirA/catB/carry.txt
dirA/catB/digit
dirA/catC/test-10.txt
dirA/catC/test-100.txt
dirA/catC/test-1000.txt
dirA/catC/test-11.txt
dirA/catC/test-2.txt
dirA/catC/test-20.txt
dirA/catC/test-25.txt
dirA/catC/test-5.txt
dirA/catC/test-50.txt
dirA/catC/test-500.txt
dirA/catC/test-7.txt
dirA/catC/test-75.txt
dirA/catC/test-8.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-9.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-999.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-75.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-8.txt
```

#### Desired Output

```
dirA/catC/abc-test-8.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-9.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-75.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-999.txt
dirA/catA/addition.txt
dirA/catA/apple.txt
dirA/catB/binary.txt
dirA/catB/carry.txt
dirA/catA/difference
dirA/catB/digit
dirA/catC/test-2.txt
dirA/catC/test-5.txt
dirA/catC/test-7.txt
dirA/catC/test-8.txt
dirA/catC/test-10.txt
dirA/catC/test-11.txt
dirA/catC/test-20.txt
dirA/catC/test-25.txt
dirA/catC/test-50.txt
dirA/catC/test-75.txt
dirA/catC/test-100.txt
dirA/catC/test-500.txt
dirA/catC/test-1000.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -e '
    print for sort { (($a =~ m{.*/([^0-9]*)})[0] cmp ($b =~ m{.*/([^0-9]*)})[0])
                     ||
                     (($a =~ /-([0-9]+)/)[0] <=> ($b =~ /-([0-9]+)/)[0]) } <>
' -- /tmp/foo.txt
```

- `<>` reads the lines of input
- [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) sorts the list based on the given code
- `m{.*/([^0-9]*)}` extracts the basename up to a digit (if present)
- `cmp` does the string comparison
- If they are equal, the `||` "or" applies the second comparison, where:
- `/-([0-9]+)/` extracts the number
- `<=>` does the numeric comparison
- The `(...)[0]` construct is needed as matching returns a list of matches (corresponding to `$1`, `$2`, etc). List context is needed to get the matches. We're interested in the first match only (as there's no other).

Answer (score 6):

```bsh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = "[-/.]"; OFS = "\t"}
    {n = 0}
    $(NF-1) ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {n = $(NF-1)}
    {print $3, n, $0}
' foo.txt \
| sort -k1,1 -k2,2n \
| cut -f3-
```

This is a [Schwarzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

- the awk program puts the first word of the filename and the file's number as columns before the file's path
- the data is sorted, first by name then by number
- then the new columns are removed.

Outputs

```
dirA/catC/abc-test-8.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-9.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-75.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-999.txt
dirA/catA/addition.txt
dirA/catA/apple.txt
dirA/catB/binary.txt
dirA/catB/carry.txt
dirA/catA/difference
dirA/catB/digit
dirA/catC/test-2.txt
dirA/catC/test-5.txt
dirA/catC/test-7.txt
dirA/catC/test-8.txt
dirA/catC/test-10.txt
dirA/catC/test-11.txt
dirA/catC/test-20.txt
dirA/catC/test-25.txt
dirA/catC/test-50.txt
dirA/catC/test-75.txt
dirA/catC/test-100.txt
dirA/catC/test-500.txt
dirA/catC/test-1000.txt
```

---

Same process with a perl one-liner (except that you read perl statements "bottom-up")

```bsh
perl -e '
  print join "",
        map  { $_->[2] }
        sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] || $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
        map  { [m{.*/(\D+)(\d*)}, $_] }
        <>;
' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
cat /tmp/foo.txt | sed "s/[[:alnum:]-]*\/[[:alnum:]-]*\/\([[:alpha:]-]*\)\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\0|\1|\2 /"|sort -t"|" -k2,2 -k3n|sed "s/\([^|]*\).*/\1/"
```

The trick is to temporarily put the desired fields to the end of the lines.

Oops: it's better:

```
cat source | sed "s/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/\([^[:digit:]]*\)\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\0|\1|\2 /"|sort -t"|" -k2,2 -k3n|sed "s/\([^|]*\).*/\1/"
```

I changed a little the original question.
Sort order the last name, without numbers.

```
dirA/catC/abc-test-8.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-9.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-75.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-999.txt
dirA/catA/addition.txt
dirA/catA/apple.txt
dirA/catB/binary.txt
dirA/catB/carry.txt
dirA/catA/difference
dirA/catB/digit
dirA/catC/test-2.txt
dirA/catC/test-5.txt
dirA/catC/test-7.txt
dirA/catC/test-8.txt
dirA/catC/test-10.txt
dirA/catC/subdir/test-11.txt
dirA/catC/test-11.txt
dirA/cat C/subdir/test-12.txt
dirA/catC/test-20.txt
dirA/catC/test-25.txt
dirA/catC/test-50.txt
dirA/catC/test-75.txt
dirA/catC/test-100.txt
dirA/catC/test-500.txt
dirA/catC/test-1000.txt
```

```
cat /tmp/foo.txt | sed "s/\([^/]*\/\)\+\([^[:digit:]]*\)\([[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\)/\0|\2\4|\3 /"|sort -t"|" -k2,2 -k3n|sed "s/\([^|]*\).*/\1/"
```

Output:

```
dirA/catC/abc-test-8.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-9.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-75.txt
dirA/catC/abc-test-999.txt
dirA/catA/addition.txt
dirA/catA/apple.txt
dirA/catB/binary.txt
dirA/catB/carry.txt
dirA/catA/difference
dirA/catB/digit
dirA/catC/test-2.txt
dirA/catC/test-5.txt
dirA/catC/test-7.txt
dirA/catC/test-8.txt
dirA/catC/test-10.txt
dirA/catC/subdir/test-11.txt
dirA/catC/test-11.txt
dirA/cat C/subdir/test-12.txt
dirA/catC/test-20.txt
dirA/catC/test-25.txt
dirA/catC/test-50.txt
dirA/catC/test-75.txt
dirA/catC/test-100.txt
dirA/catC/test-500.txt
dirA/catC/test-1000.txt
```

Explain:
`\([^/]*\/\)\+` Cut the whole path. =>\1

`\([^[:digit:]]*\)` file name part without digits =>\2

`\([[:digit:]]*\)` digits =>3
`\(.*\)` extension =>4

`\0|\2\4|\3` Print the whole line | file name 1st part and the extension | digits

`sort -t"|" -k2,2 -k3n|sed "s/\([^|]*\).*/\1/` sort, and cut the unnecessary parts.

Instead of last sed `cut -d "|" -f1` also works

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me on Mac OS 11.4. Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question, but perhaps it will be useful to others.

Comment: Hmmmm. Why not? What is the cat /tmp/foo.txt | sed "s/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/\([^[:digit:]]*\)\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\0|\1|\2 /" 
output?